# Python DJANGO 3.0 issue with passing arguments to @register.simple_tag

Tags: python-3.x, django, templatetags, listdir

I have the following tree:

- apps
- templatetags

  - pyos.py
- templates

  - index.html

In pyos.py I have the following code:

```
import os
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def listdir(path):
    d = os.listdir
    return d(path)


def test():
    pass
```

Then in index.html, inside templates I have the following already working:

```
{%extends 'principal.html'%}
<div> 
    {%load pyos%}

    {%listdir 'C:/'%}

</div>
```

I need to pass some **static path** as argument, is there any way to do something like that?

```
<div> 

    {%load pyos%}
    {%load static%}

    {%listdir {%static 'img/imagesFolder%}%}

</div>
```

Comment: Note: settings are alright

Comment: static template tag does not return system path but URL , it is unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to get a path list of files to display the images, but i need the static path

Comment: So i appreciate the info, but can u write me some solution for that then? I'm very new at this